# Dynamic network data

Tags: data-request, network-structure

I'm looking for a data set that is network data along with some kind of measure for each node at each time point, e.g. student performance data with data on who is working with whom in groups.

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://data.stackexchange.com/.
You have groups (one question, multiple people involved(questioner, answerer, commenter)) and you can measure their contribution (score for action). Each node on their own has a total score. It's a big, real and diverse dataset.